# math equation for fighting

Tags: c#, algorithm, equation

I have the following code for a fight but the user will win around 99.9% of the time (tested with 5000 random loops)

I have the following variables that affect the fight

strength | defence | dexterity | damage | portal difficulty (always + 1 to stop * by 0) | critical

This is what I have so far

```
//player variable 
//(int) player.itemDamage = 20
//(int) player.itemStr = 2
//(int) player.itemDex = 4

            int defense = (int)Math.Round((((portal + 1) * ((rand.NextDouble() + 0.5))) + 5) / 2, 0);
            int damage = (int)Math.Round((((portal + 1) * ((rand.NextDouble() + 0.5))) + player.itemDamage), 0);
            int str = (int)Math.Round((((portal + 1) * ((rand.NextDouble() + 0.5))) + player.itemStr), 0);
            int dex = (int)Math.Round((((portal + 1) * ((rand.NextDouble() + 0.5))) + player.itemDex), 0);
while(true)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    critical += rand.NextDouble();
                }
                eHP -= (int)Math.Round((((player.itemDamage + player.itemStr) - defense) * critical) / 2, 0);
                critical = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    critical += rand.NextDouble();
                }
                HP -= (int)Math.Round((((damage + str) - 5) * critical) / 2, 0);

                if (eHP <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
else if (HP <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                }
```

What could I change in the following code to let the user (HP) win 70% of the time can I get some suggestions please? I am terrible with algorithms
Edit: Although I want the user to win 70% of the time I still want it to be round based on damage not using a simple if(0 > 70) win else loose statement because that wouldn't be a very interesting fight.

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: I have given all the information in the code what do you need to know?

Comment: I can tell you what it does but not what it's supposed to do.

Comment: What could I change in the following code to let the user (HP) win 70% of the time can I get some suggestions please? I am terrible with algorithms

Comment: One suggestion: `if(rand.nextDouble()<0.7) win(); else lose();`

Comment: @JordanTrainor Scrap the code and do it again. Please edit the question and explain, in words, what the logic is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all seriousness, it is understandable why you are having trouble with this based on how you are approaching it with code. You should instead treat it like a math function.

Create a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) `f` from a set of inputs `(x, y, ..., z)` to a `boolean` output. There should not be any usage of `rand` in this function. If you need random input, pass then into the function. Try doing it first without overwriting existing variables (don't use `+=`/`-=`). For every `(x, y, z)`, `f(x, y, z)` should always result in the same output. If you do this, it should be pretty easy to use maths to solve for the missing values.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rand.next(10) > 7) {
    //user wins
} else {
    //user loses
}
```

Comment: +1 This perfectly points out the ambiguity in the asker's question AND complies with the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As drstevens says, your implementation would be better off split into smaller, pure functions.

In particular, the number of hit points lost appears to be proportional to the value of `critical`. The code you give does not show what the value of `critical` is when the loop starts, but after the first iteration the value will be about 5 higher when reducing 'enemy' hit points than when reducing 'user' hit points in the previous iteration, because you don't set it to 1 before adding ten random numbers to it. As `critical` for user is generally around 11 and for enemy around 6, it would take a strong enemy to win ( for example, one where `defence` is greater than the user's strength and item damage, so it gains hit points if you hit them!).

If you had written a pure function which calculated either `critical` or the number of hit points to subtract, this error would not have happened.